# Colored xtrace output

Tags: bash, shell

I have a .sh-script that uses `set -o xtrace` to print all following commands.
I want to color these commands. I tried to use the PS4 variable like this:

```
export PS4='\[\e[36m\]\+ \[\e[m\]'
```

But this colors only the `+`-character and if i leave out `\[\e[m\]` my complete output and the output of the executed program is colored.
Is there another variable that is appended after the printed command where I can reset the color or is there another way.
Thanks.

Comment: There's nothing simple you can set. You might try piping all of standard error through a process substitution that wraps lines looking like part of the trace output, but it's tricky (I don't have a working version to post as an answer yet.)

Comment: Hm, scratch that. Due to the asynchronous nature of process substitution, there's no guaranteed that the trace output and the regular output will be interleaved properly. You might be able to configure your terminal to display certain lines differently, but this isn't possible purely at the shell level.

Comment: As @chepner explained that it is tricky to do that at the shell level (and I didn't find any other way), I made a hacky workaround: modified the `xtrace_print` functions to use colors directly in the `fprintf` calls. When executing your script you just need to use your `bash_colored` binary. As it is for debugging purposes, maybe it is helpful for someone. I'll post it as an answer later today.

Comment: If you use something like `export PS4="$(printf "%b" "\033[35m${PS4}\033[0m")"` in your `~/.bashrc`, you will be able to set colors in your `$PS4` var. Anyway, if you are making use of `$PROMPT_COMMAND`, it will be wrote over and over again after the execution of your command.

Answer (score 2):

## The Gist

Because of the way terminal coloring works, combined with the say bash tracing works, it's pretty ugly to implement, but here's how you do it:

First, you need to find some unique string that will appear neither in the trace, nor in stdout, nor in stderr. In my example, it's `@@@`.

Then, if your script is called `example.sh`, you run

```
$ ./color_trace.sh example.sh
```

Where `./color_trace.sh` is this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

RED=1
UNIQUE_STR='@@@'

COLOR=$RED

normal()
{
    tput sgr0 # tell the terminal to not style the output
}

colored()
{
    tput setaf $COLOR # tell the terminal to set forward color to $COLOR
}

export PS4="+${UNIQUE_STR}" # artificially insert $UNIQUE_STR to the trace
exec &> >(sed "s/\(\+\)*\+\(${UNIQUE_STR}\)\(.*\)$/$(colored)\1+\3$(normal)/") # see below
set -x # set trace
source "$@" # run the commands in the current shell so that all settings apply
```

This will color trace commands [red](https://linux.101hacks.com/ps1-examples/prompt-color-using-tput/).

## Explanation

The way it does it is as follows:

- Insert `$UNIQUE_STR` to the output
- Route all output - stdout and stderr - through a command (`exec &> >(...)`)
- The command (`sed`) assumes the trace is of the form `+++${UNIQUE_STR} <some interesting trace>`
- Find lines with `$UNIQUE_STR` (`s/...\(${UNIQUE_STR}\).../`) and remove it (`/...\1+\3.../`, where `\1` is `++` and `\3` is `<some interesting trace>`)
- If the line does containe `$UNIQUE_STR`, tell the terminal to set the coloring to red before the line, and to unset coloring after the line (`/$(colored)...$(normal)/`).

## What doesn't work

First, the functions `colored()` and `normal()` don't accept a piece of text to color. Instead, they instruct the terminal to set the color to whatever is going to be written next, and after it's written, instruct it to unset coloring. This is just how coloring, or any kind of styling, works in Unix terminals.

Second, The trace goes to stderr, so it will be mixed with other output of stderr. This could be changed using [`BASH_XTRACEFD`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/811439/bash-set-x-logs-to-file), but it wouldn't work well here.

Since you want coloring, it is assumed that you want to differentiate the trace from other output, so it is assumed that all the output, including stdout, stderr, and the trace, is going to the terminal.

If everything is going to the terminal, then in order for the trace to be properly interleaved with the actual output, all output - stdout, stderr, and the trace - need to be executed on the same file descriptor. That's why we have to redirect everything through `sed`, not just the trace. If we only redirected the trace, then you'll get a bunch of output from various commands, and only afterwards you'll see all the traces for these commands, e.g.

```
... actual output from /etc/passwd...
... actual output from /etc/group...
+source ./script.sh
++cat_file /etc/passwd
++cat /etc/passwd
++cat_file /etc/group
++cat /etc/group
```

If it weren't for the file descriptor problem, we wouldn't need `UNIQUE_STR`, we could have just used something like:

```
exec 19> >(sed "s/^.*$/$(colored)&$(normal)/")
BASH_XTRACEFD=19
set -x
source "$@"
```

It's worth noting that even in this version we would have to turn colors on and off every line, because lines of "real output" need to be uncolored.

Comment: Clever use of `exec`, I hadn't considered this approach. The need for an in-band delimiter (`$UNIQUE_STR`) is too bad, but seems like a reasonable tradeoff. I would personally inline the `tput` calls (or just using escape sequences directly) to avoid needing the `colored` and `normal` functions. You probably want to use `^` at the beginning of the `sed` pattern, as well.

Comment: I used function for the answer to be more readable. You don't strictly need `^` because `UNIQUE_STR` is assumed to be unique, so it has to be where I expect it to be.

Comment: To avoid misinterpreting the filename as the first argument, I had to use `shift`. i.e. https://gist.github.com/akhiljalagam/a81d1125ad8447953f6794604dacef87

Answer (score 1):

The introduction of [`PS0` in Bash 4.4](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2016-09/msg00012.html) *almost* allows us to do what you need; `PS0='\e[0m'` writes a reset code to the terminal before each command runs, but unfortunately it's printed before, not after, `PS4` is printed, so that's no good. As others have said I don't think you can do what you want today with bash; `PS4` simply isn't an expressive enough hook to properly color the command trace, and there's no other hook that fires at the right time.

Depending on your exact goal, you may be able to use the `DEBUG` trap *instead* of `-x`. It doesn't perfectly replicate `-x`, but we can get a similar effect.

```
$ debug() {
  # print a '+' for every element in BASH_LINENO, similar to PS4's behavior
  printf '%s' "${BASH_LINENO[@]/*/+}"
  # Then print the current command, colored
  printf ' \e[36m%s\e[0m\n' "$BASH_COMMAND"
}
$ trap debug DEBUG
$ shopt -s extdebug # necessary for the DEBUG trap to carry into functions
```

This *mostly* works, though the debug trap doesn't exactly mirror `-x`'s behavior, so the output is a little different. Here's an example:

```
$ foo() { bar "$@"; }
$ bar() { printf '%s\n' "$@" | grep baz; }
$ foo biff bang baz
+ foo biff bang baz
++ foo biff bang baz
++ bar "$@"
+++ bar "$@"
+++ printf '%s\n' "$@"
+++ grep baz
baz
```

I'm not immediately certain why the function calls `foo` and `bar` print twice, though I think the second entries are the DEBUG trap entering the function, which we might be able to detect and suppress somehow, e.g. by inspecting `FUNCNAME` or `BASH_LINENO`. I'll update this answer if I work that out.

Comment: This is EPIC! I have been thinking about the need for a `$PS5` var (and have it sent after the trace) for about 2 decades. I love this solution even more than what I was seeking. You're never too experinced to fall for the classic [XY_Problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem#line-106)

Answer (score -2):

```
export PS4=$'+\e[33m $BASH_SOURCE:${BASH_LINENO[0]} ${FUNCNAME[0]:-NOFUNC}() \e[0m+  '
```

From `man bash`

> `PS4`    The value of this parameter is expanded as with PS1 and the value is printed
>       before  each  command  bash  displays  during an execution trace.  The first
>         character of the expanded value of PS4 is replicated multiple times, as nesessary,  to indicate multiple levels of indirection.  The default is ``+ ''.

Comment: This demonstrates that it's possible to include colors in the `PS4` output (which OP already knew) but doesn't address the question of coloring the command bash prints *after* the `PS4` output.

Answer (score -5):

I'm coloring whole my terminal by using PS1 var, bellow is my sample, so that it is full clear which color is what(as well as adding git branch before folder name in term):

```
Color_Off="\[\033[0m\]"       # Text Reset

# Regular Colors
Black="\[\033[0;30m\]"        # Black
Red="\[\033[0;31m\]"          # Red
Green="\[\033[0;32m\]"        # Green
Yellow="\[\033[0;33m\]"       # Yellow
Blue="\[\033[0;34m\]"         # Blue
Purple="\[\033[0;35m\]"       # Purple
Cyan="\[\033[0;36m\]"         # Cyan
White="\[\033[0;37m\]"        # White

# Bold
BBlack="\[\033[1;30m\]"       # Black
BRed="\[\033[1;31m\]"         # Red
BGreen="\[\033[1;32m\]"       # Green
BYellow="\[\033[1;33m\]"      # Yellow
BBlue="\[\033[1;34m\]"        # Blue
BPurple="\[\033[1;35m\]"      # Purple
BCyan="\[\033[1;36m\]"        # Cyan
BWhite="\[\033[1;37m\]"       # White

# Underline
UBlack="\[\033[4;30m\]"       # Black
URed="\[\033[4;31m\]"         # Red
UGreen="\[\033[4;32m\]"       # Green
UYellow="\[\033[4;33m\]"      # Yellow
UBlue="\[\033[4;34m\]"        # Blue
UPurple="\[\033[4;35m\]"      # Purple
UCyan="\[\033[4;36m\]"        # Cyan
UWhite="\[\033[4;37m\]"       # White

# Background
On_Black="\[\033[40m\]"       # Black
On_Red="\[\033[41m\]"         # Red
On_Green="\[\033[42m\]"       # Green
On_Yellow="\[\033[43m\]"      # Yellow
On_Blue="\[\033[44m\]"        # Blue
On_Purple="\[\033[45m\]"      # Purple
On_Cyan="\[\033[46m\]"        # Cyan
On_White="\[\033[47m\]"       # White

# High Intensty
IBlack="\[\033[0;90m\]"       # Black
IRed="\[\033[0;91m\]"         # Red
IGreen="\[\033[0;92m\]"       # Green
IYellow="\[\033[0;93m\]"      # Yellow
IBlue="\[\033[0;94m\]"        # Blue
IPurple="\[\033[0;95m\]"      # Purple
ICyan="\[\033[0;96m\]"        # Cyan
IWhite="\[\033[0;97m\]"       # White

# Bold High Intensty
BIBlack="\[\033[1;90m\]"      # Black
BIRed="\[\033[1;91m\]"        # Red
BIGreen="\[\033[1;92m\]"      # Green
BIYellow="\[\033[1;93m\]"     # Yellow
BIBlue="\[\033[1;94m\]"       # Blue
BIPurple="\[\033[1;95m\]"     # Purple
BICyan="\[\033[1;96m\]"       # Cyan
BIWhite="\[\033[1;97m\]"      # White

# High Intensty backgrounds
On_IBlack="\[\033[0;100m\]"   # Black
On_IRed="\[\033[0;101m\]"     # Red
On_IGreen="\[\033[0;102m\]"   # Green
On_IYellow="\[\033[0;103m\]"  # Yellow
On_IBlue="\[\033[0;104m\]"    # Blue
On_IPurple="\[\033[10;95m\]"  # Purple
On_ICyan="\[\033[0;106m\]"    # Cyan
On_IWhite="\[\033[0;107m\]"   # White

Time12h="\T"
Time12a="\@"
PathShort="\w"
PathFull="\W"
NewLine="\n"
Jobs="\j"
User="\u"
Host="\h"
Dollar="\$ "

gitBranch='`git branch 2> /dev/null | grep -e ^* | sed -E  s/^\\\\\*\ \(.+\)$/\(\\\\\1\)\ /`'

export PS1=$BPurple$gitBranch$BRed$PathShort$NewLine$BBlue$Dollar$Color_Off
```