# POSIX shell (sh) redirect stderr to stdout and capture stderr and stdout into variables

Tags: sh, posix, stdout, stderr

I would like to redirect stderr to stdout so a terminal prints both of them during a command execution but I would like also to capture both of them into separate variables. I managed to achieve that in Bash (version 4.4.20(1)-release):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "terminal:"
{ err="$(find / -maxdepth 2 -iname 'tmp' -type d 2>&1 1>&3 3>&- | tee /dev/stderr)"; ec="$?"; } 3>&1 | tee /dev/fd/4 2>&1; out=$(cat /dev/fd/4)
echo "stdout:" && echo "$out"
echo "stderr:" && echo "$err"
```

that gives desired:

```
terminal:
find: ‘/root’: Permission denied
/tmp
/var/tmp
find: ‘/lost+found’: Permission denied
stdout:
/tmp
/var/tmp
stderr:
find: ‘/root’: Permission denied
find: ‘/lost+found’: Permission denied
```

but I have a problem converting that script into POSIX sh `/bin/sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "terminal:"
{ err="$(find / -maxdepth 2 -iname 'tmp' -type d 2>&1 1>&3 3>&- | tee /dev/stderr)"; ec="$?"; } 3>&1 | tee /dev/fd/4 2>&1; out=$(cat /dev/fd/4)
echo "stdout:" && echo "$out"
echo "stderr:" && echo "$err"
```

gives:

```
terminal:
tee: /dev/fd/4: No such file or directory
find: ‘/root’: Permission denied
/tmp
/var/tmp
find: ‘/lost+found’: Permission denied
cat: /dev/fd/4: No such file or directory
stdout:

stderr:
```

`/dev/fd/4` does not exist, and there is no `/proc/self/fd/4` either.

How to make that script working as a POSIX shell script?

Comment: The shell is creating the file descriptors in `/dev/fd` for you. Probably replace that with your own FIFO in `/tmp`.

Comment: I'm surprised this works in `bash`; it's only documented as treating `/dev/fd` specially in redirections, not as arguments to `tee` or `cat`.

Comment: [Under linux] the `/dev/fd` paths are not bash-isms; those are provided by the Linux kernel and are available in any process.

Comment: @Jimmix your code doesn't work on my bash 5.0.17 (Linux). I don't think what you want is possible, but I've explored it in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65068684/10678955 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/62055496/10678955, maybe that will help.

Comment: @root I noticed after restarting my machine it did not work as well but before it worked. I think that during the development I must altered my machine by trying different approaches. I remember that there was also strange to me that the code worked well in one terminal instance but on the other (same machine) it did not work. I played a lot till i reached the final code so I assume unintentionally changed the behavior of the shell. I am pretty sure it worked at some point :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm doing this in busybox's `ash` shell and my options are rather limited, but this is what I came up with that works.

```sh
tmpfile=/tmp/some_prefix_stderr.$$
out=$(my_cmd) 2>$tmpfile
result=$?
err=$(cat $tmpfile)
rm $tmpfile
```

It's not the prettiest, but it works.  In general, replace `some_prefix` with something specific to help avoid collisions, but just having the PID on there will solve that unless you are running multiple threads.

If you can rely upon your program exiting non-zero when there's something to show in stderr, you can simplify it a little:

```sh
tmpfile=/tmp/some_prefix_stderr.$$
if ! out=$(my_cmd) 2>$tmpfile; then
    # specific behavior here
    cat $tmpfile >&2
fi
rm $tmpfile
```

This is all POSIX compliant.  Just be sure to clean up your temp file.

Comment: You might want to add some additional quoting (http://shellcheck.net/ will point out most of the places where it's needed) to make the script work correctly in contexts with weird IFS values (`IFS=/` is a good exercise to make problems visible).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I can't blame you for thinking that, but no additional quotes are needed.  It's not terribly friendly language, but it's outlined in [§2.9.1 Simple Commands](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01) of the POSIX specification.  In essence "The words that are recognized as variable assignments or redirections" are expanded after field separation.  So if your assignment is a single word, then it doesn't need quotes.  For example, this is valid: `jack=I${IFS}went${IFS}fishing`

Comment: Yes, that's correct in assignments, but not every case exercised in this code is an assignment. `cat $tmpfile` and `rm $tmpfile` are not, and the `IFS=/` scenario in particular applies to them (you can get argument vectors of `cat tmp some_prefix_sterr.PID` f/e).

Comment: Also, some versions of bash are arguably buggy and can throw errors when a redirection's content word-splits to other than exactly one element. I believe that's fixed in modern releases (and word-splitting is suppressed in redirections just as in assignments), but less need to caveat code with portability warnings when one chooses to err on the side of caution.

Comment: Hello @CharlesDuffy.  You are correct that `IFS=/` would break this.  I would guess that 99% of shell script code in existance expects an unmodified `IFS`, so this comes down to coding standard where there are many compelling arguments for various issues and the maintainer simply must make the decision.

In general, I side with higher readability, simplicity and maintainability as my experience shows it result higher reliability and fewer errors, bugs and surprises.  Thus, I do not inject unnecessary syntax to make it compatible with "corner cases", such as a modified `IFS`.

Comment: IFS modifications aren't the only corner case where unquoted expansions get dicey. `nullglob` and `failglob` make things that can be interpreted as glob expressions behave unexpectedly even when they don't match any files, f/e. I disagree strenuously with any suggestion that code with corner cases hidden from unfamiliar readers is more maintainable than code that's written to explicitly foreclose them: A reviewer who sees something unfamiliar and asks "why did you do this?" learns something, whereas a reviewer who sees nothing out of the ordinary because they don't know where the pitfalls[...]

Comment: [...]live is a reviewer who doesn't know what assertions they need to validate truth of to ensure code's correctness in the context in which it's being run.

Comment: (The other thing is that even very rare failures can be expensive; one of the worst data loss incidents I've personally witnessed in terms of financial impact was caused by a backup-maintenance tool running `rm -rf $file` with a filename that could only be generated by trusted code written in a memory-safe language; no reason to bother quoting, right? But one day a new producer was added in a _different_ memory-safe language that used a C library via FFI; that C library had a bug, and corrupted memory that was used in filename generation, and a filename with a whitespace-surrounded `*`[...]

Comment: [...]was introduced onto the filesystem the backup-pruning script ran against; the ops team I worked with had a lot of members with decades of experience, and none of them had personally had that happen to them yet -- but it wiped data that was used to back customer billing for a high-volume cloud service; counting on "eh, it's an unlikely/rare failure" can bite one hard when that rare event finally does happen).

Comment: Resisting such a simple robustness fix is weird. Really, just add the missing quotes; in the absolutely worst case, they are unnecessary but harmless.

Comment: @tripleee You can have your fluffy code and I'll stick to knowing exactly what I'm doing and exactly what the specification is. I suppose there are arguments for both side, but I'll stick with correctness and simplicity.